# Merge rows with messages in same timespan grouped by sender

Tags: r, time, group-by, merge

I have a dataframe that contains messages from senders from whatsapp. Usually, people tend to use more than one message to say something in whatsapp. My goal is to merge the messages that have been send in a timeframe of about 5 minutes into one row. This has to be grouped by sender, because the dataframe contains multiple senders. My dataframe looks something like the following:

```
Message             Time                    Sender
hello               2018-12-14 16:27:00     300
how are you?        2018-12-14 16:29:00     300
do you reply?       2018-12-15 12:00:00     300
Hi                  2018-12-14 16:30:00     200
Hi                  2018-12-15 16:36:00     200
```

Now I want it to look like this:

```
Message             Time                    Sender
hello how are you?  2018-12-14 16:27:00     300
do you reply?       2018-12-15 12:00:00     300
Hi                  2018-12-14 16:30:00     200
Hi                  2018-12-15 16:3600      200
```

The first and the second have been merged. My attempt so far was to use group_map together with a reduce, but I can't seem to find the solution.

```
joinedMessageTable <- messageTable %>% group_by(Sender) %>% group_map(function(table, sender) {
    Reduce(function(firstElement, result) {
        value <- (firstElement + 5 *60 > result)
    }, table$time)
})
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what about when the messages are sent within 5 minutes of each other, but during a periode >5 minutes? Example: a message from Sender 300 is sent on 1:05, 1:09, 1:11 and 1:15. Do you still want to merge all four of them together?

Comment: Yes, I sitll want to merge those. I want it to be based on the latest send message in the timeframe. So 1:05 + 5 = 1:10. 1:09 is included. 1:09 + 5 = 1:14. So 1:11 is included. 1:11 + 5 = 1:16, so 1:15 is also included.

Comment: It is easier to help if you provide data in a format which is easier to copy preferably with `dput`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ceiling_date` to create group of every 5 mins -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

messageTable %>%
  group_by(Sender, Time = ceiling_date(mdy_hm(Time), unit = '5 mins')) %>%
  summarise(Message = paste0(Message, collapse = ' ')) %>%
  ungroup
```

For 5 mins duration if you want to consider difference between consecutive values you can do -

```
df %>%
  mutate(Time = mdy_hm(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Sender) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(difftime(Time, 
                   lag(Time, default = first(Time)), units = 'mins') > 5)) %>%
  group_by(group, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(Message = paste0(Message, collapse = ' ')) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: I used grouping with `cut` from base R. It works partially. The groups are hard cut. Messages that should be merged, don't get merged. This is for the case Wimpel described in the comment

Comment: Can you try my edited answer with `difftime` ?

Comment: Yes, this seems to work! Thank you! I do have some more columns though. How do I keep them?

Comment: You can use `mutate` instead of `summarise` at the end so that this will add a new column to your existing dataset. You can also remove columns which you don't need using `select(-group)` etc.

Comment: I have duplicate message columns now. How do I remove those? With distinct on message this does not work, since I have multiple persons saying only "hi". Maybe with distinct on message and sender?

Comment: Yes, maybe you can use `%>% distinct(Sender, Message, .keep_all = TRUE)` which will keep first row of each combination.

Comment: On closer inspection, this almost worked. Using your technique I solved it myself, I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Sender) %>% 
   mutate(flag = +(difftime(lead(Time), Time, units = 'min') < 5), flag = replace_na(flag, 0),
          Message = case_when(flag == 1 ~ str_c(Message, lead(Message), sep = ' '), TRUE ~ Message),
          Time = case_when(lag(flag) == 1 & flag == 0 ~ lag(Time), TRUE ~ Time)) %>% select(-flag) %>% filter(!duplicated(Time))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Sender [2]
  Message            Time                Sender
  <chr>              <dttm>               <dbl>
1 hello how are you? 2018-12-14 16:27:00    300
2 do you reply?      2018-12-15 12:00:00    300
3 Hi                 2018-12-14 16:30:00    200
4 Hi                 2018-12-15 16:36:00    200
```

Comment: It gives the following error:
"Problem with `mutate()` input `flag`.
✖ character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
ℹ Input `flag` is `+(difftime(lead(time), time, units = "min") < 5)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Sender = 1."

My time is in POSIXct format, it might have something to do with that?

Comment: @JoostLuijben, Even the above data is in `POSIXct` format. Did you check `str()` of your dataframe?

Comment: That gives the following value for time `$ time        : chr  "2/22/2020, 11:48" "2/26/2020, 13:15" "2/26/2020, 06:21" "1/29/2020, 24:07" ...` Do I need to convert this to a date? I used the following before to change it to the right format `as.POSIXct(joinedFrame$time, format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M")`. I am quite new to R, so I don't know the datatypes that it has

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. Time was a string and not a POSIXct type. I converted it to posixct

Comment: This solution does not work yet like desired. If there's one extra message with timestamp `2018-12-14 16:31:00` it is not included. I think because lead takes only the next element, but I need all the elements

Answer (score 0):

You may also `runner` (library for calculating sliding windows/rolling computation) if the output is of some help to you,

```r
my_df <- read.table(text = "Message             Time                    Sender
'hello'               '2018-12-14 16:27:00'     300
'how are you?'        '2018-12-14 16:29:00'     300
'do you reply?'       '2018-12-15 12:00:00'     300
'Hi'                  '2018-12-14 16:30:00'     200
'Hi'                  '2018-12-15 16:36:00'     200", header = T)

my_df$Time <- as.POSIXct(my_df$Time)

library(tidyverse)
library(runner)

my_df %>% group_by(Sender) %>%
  mutate(msg = runner(Message,
                      idx = Time,
                      k = '5 mins',
                      f = toString))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   Sender [2]
#>   Message       Time                Sender msg                
#>   <chr>         <dttm>               <int> <chr>              
#> 1 hello         2018-12-14 16:27:00    300 hello              
#> 2 how are you?  2018-12-14 16:29:00    300 hello, how are you?
#> 3 do you reply? 2018-12-15 12:00:00    300 do you reply?      
#> 4 Hi            2018-12-14 16:30:00    200 Hi                 
#> 5 Hi            2018-12-15 16:36:00    200 Hi
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

messageTable %>%
  group_by(Sender, Time = ceiling_date(mdy_hm(Time), unit = '5 mins')) %>%
  summarise(Message = toString(Message), .groups = 'drop')
```

Answer (score 0):

After closing inspection the solution @Ronak gave didn't fully work. I used some of this code to make my own implementation. The problem Ronak's code has is that it groups using false and true, thus only two groups of time can be made. Matter of fact is that I need to have multiple groups with multiple senders based on the time with a cumulative window.

The solution I came up with isn't really confirm the R philosophy so feel free to improve it.

```
my_df <- read.table(text = "Message             Time                    Sender
                       'hello'               '2018-12-14 16:27:00'     300
                       'how are you?'        '2018-12-14 16:34:00'     300
                       'are you good?'       '2018-12-14 16:29:00'     300
                       'do you reply?'       '2018-12-15 12:00:00'     300
                       'Have you received?'  '2018-12-15 16:34:00'     300
                       'are you good?'       '2018-12-15 16:29:00'     300
                       'Hi'                  '2018-12-14 16:30:00'     200
                       'Hi'                  '2018-12-15 16:36:00'     200
                       'Who is this?'        '2018-12-15 16:35:00'     100
                       'Hi'                  '2018-12-15 16:35:00'     100", header = T)

my_df$Time <- as.POSIXct(my_df$Time)

merged_df <- my_df %>% 
  group_by(Sender, Time) %>% 
  mutate(Message = paste0(Message, collapse = " ")) %>%
  distinct(Message, Sender, Time, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Sender) %>%
  arrange(Time) %>%
  group_modify(function(table, sender) {
    counter <<- 1
    begin <<- first(table$Time)
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(table))) {
      if (isTRUE(abs(difftime(begin, table[i,]$Time, units = "mins")) > 5)) {
        counter <<- counter + 1
      }
      begin <<- table[i,]$Time
      table[i, "counter"] <- counter
    }
    table
  }) %>%
  group_by(Sender, counter, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    Message = paste0(Message, collapse = ' ')
  ) %>%
  distinct(Sender, counter, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-counter)
```

**Edit**
As Ronak pointed out the problem stated above isn't really the problem. Using an arrange it solves the problem. The full solution would be:

```
df <- joinedFrame %>%
  group_by(Sender) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(difftime(time,
                               lag(time, default = first(time)), units = 'mins') > 5)) %>%
  group_by(group, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(English = paste0(English, collapse = ' ')) %>%
  ungroup %>% distinct(Sender, group, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

I keep my solution and the conversation above for reference

Comment: `The problem Ronak's code has is that it groups using false and true, thus only two groups of time can be made.` that is not true. I have used `cumsum` over the false/true values so every-time `TRUE` is encountered it increments the count.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I think the problem is that my full dataframe wasn't orderd. Using arrange your solution seems to work